# How can I run my Python Telegram bot on a cloud server?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have just started learning Telegram bot With [python-telegram-bot](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0a2/).

I want to run my bot on a cloud server and I don't want to use heroku or services like this.

I hope you help me how to setup my bot on a cloud server or webhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply run your python program which you wrote using a systemd service in  a linux based servers.

Setup the server for that python program to run(installing python3 and installing dependencies) and start the service. This way your program will be running forever.

I am linking to a tutorial for the same: https://tecadmin.net/setup-autorun-python-script-using-systemd

Comment: Thank you, It's working now!!
can you tell me how to stop it?

Comment: To stop this service, use `sudo systemctl stop <service-name>` But this will only stop until next reboot if you have enabled it. To disable it completely, use `sudo systemctl disable <service-name>`

Comment: If i want to Update my python program, I have to stop or disable it and do those steps again?

Comment: For that just update the code, and restart the service using, `sudo systemctl restart <service-name>`